# Buttons location not updating properly after PanGesture

Tags: ios, swift

I've set my buttons to a position to move with the camera as I use the Pan Gesture to move around my Tilemap background. However, when I go to click the button it does not work. It works if I open the scene and do not move the camera with Pan Gesture. So, I am assuming that the location of the button is not updating properly, although it is visibly moving with the camera.

[This is the First part of the Scene before movement occurs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxJPy.png)
[This is the second part of the Scene after I have used the Pan Gesture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFXyC.png)

As you can see from the photos, the buttons are moving as I want them to. However, when I click the Rim image, it doesn't work properly in the second image.

Below is my relevant code:

```
func addButtonstoScene()
{
    //Hint Button
    buttonHint.position = CGPoint(x: (camera?.position.x)! + buttonHintXOffset, y: (camera?.position.y)! + buttonYOffset)
    buttonHint.name = "Hint"
    buttonHint.size = CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    buttonHint.isHidden = false
    //Fast Forward Button
    buttonFastForward.position = CGPoint(x: (camera?.position.x)! + buttonFastForwardXOffset, y: (camera?.position.y)! + buttonYOffset)
    buttonFastForward.name = "Hint"
    buttonFastForward.size = CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    buttonFastForward.isHidden = false
    //Settings Button
    buttonSettings.position = CGPoint(x: (camera?.position.x)! + buttonSettingsXOffset, y: (camera?.position.y)! + buttonYOffset)
    buttonSettings.name = "Settings"
    buttonSettings.size = CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    buttonSettings.zPosition = 2000

    camera?.addChild(buttonHint)
    camera?.addChild(buttonFastForward)
    camera?.addChild(buttonSettings)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if buttonSettings.contains(location)
        {
            let transitions: SKTransition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: transitionTime)
            let scene: SKScene = OptionsScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transitions)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after a little while of trying to figure out what i did wrong, I was able to solve this. The correction is to have the location(in: camera!)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    for touch in touches
    {
        let location = touch.location(in: camera!)
        if buttonSettings.contains(location)
        {
            let transitions: SKTransition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: transitionTime)
            let scene: SKScene = OptionsScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536))
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transitions)
        }
    }
}
```